# Libclang python bindings on windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, libclang

I'm trying to explore libclang (on Windows) to do "stuff*" based on parsing the AST.  I find several examples, I'm unable to get anything to work.

When I try to run this

```
index = clang.cindex.Index.create()
tu = index.parse(sys.argv[1], args=['-x', 'c++'])
print len(tu.cursor.get_children())
```

I get an access violation,

`File "C:\python27\lib\site-packages\clang\cindex.py", line 1783, in get_children
    children)
    WindowsError: exception: access violation writing 0x000000001D1B81A8`

The cindex.py is slightly different in here (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/bindings/python) but gives the same result, just a different line.

Additionally, it appears there are a few outstanding bugs (https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=13907) that sound very similar... although several years old now.

**With that, is anyone currently using this on Windows?**  It appears this may have worked at some point...

[It appears libclang is the recommended](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html) way of doing this, and python is easy to use, but doesn't appear functional.

*Note: by stuff, I want to generate serialization functions or bindings using attributes to mark up classes/structs.

LLVM 7.0 (and 6.0)
Windows 10
python 2.7 x64